# How do I undo All of what i drew

Tags: java, swing

So I want to clean my window after I draw on it my boxes and triangles and some other

shapes. I need to click on a button and undo everything like they all should be gone from

the window and everything is cleaned up.

Here I did a box and when I click the Button box and click in the window a box show up where

ever i click.

I did the same for the triangle as i did for the boxes.

This is the main program ( with only the boxes):

```
    import java.awt.*;

    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Kaleidescope extends JFrame implements MouseListener, ActionListener,

            MouseMotionListener {

        Triangle L;

        Triangle[] triangles;

        int triangleCount;

        Box b;

        Box[] boxes; // 2-d array of Box objects, form a color pallet

        int boxCount; 

        JButton boxButton;

        Oval O;

        Oval[] ovals;

        int ovalCount;

        Oval v; // Oval x, y 

        int downX=0, downY=0, upX=0, upY=0;

        int x1, y1; // mousePressed

        int w1, z1; // mouseEntered

        int mode = 1; // 1 = line, 2= boxes, 3 = oval, 4= text, 5 = SG, twoLines = 7.

        JButton TriangleButton;

        JButton boxButton;

        boolean Boxe = false; // if true draw box

        JButton ovalButton;

        int x1, y1; // mousePressed

        int w1, z1; // mouseEntered

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

            System.out.println("hi there.");

            new Kaleidescope();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            addMouseListener(this);

            addMouseMotionListener(this);

             triangles = new Triangle[20];

             triangleCount = 0; 

             boxes = new Box[20];

             boxCount = 0; 

             ovals = new Oval[20];
             ovalCount = 0;

            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            boxButton = new JButton("Boxes");

            add(boxButton);

            boxButton.addActionListener(this);

            TriangleButton = new JButton("Triangles");

            add(TriangleButton);

            TriangleButton.addActionListener( this);

            ovalButton = new JButton("Oval");

            add(ovalButton);

            ovalButton.addActionListener( this);

            setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

            setVisible(true);
        }

   // returns a random color

   public Color randomColor()

   {    

      int red = (int)(Math.random()*255);

      int green = (int)(Math.random()*255);

      int blue = (int)(Math.random()*255);

      return new Color(red,green,blue);    
   }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {

        System.out.println("click at x="+e.getX()+" y="+e.getY()); 

        // convert window coords to box array indexes.

        // These were adjusted slightly after the video was made

        // (no more flakiness, these are right on target).

        int boxi = (e.getX()-10)/20; // convert mouse x to box index

        int boxj = (e.getY()-40)/20;

        System.out.println("click at boxi="+boxi+" boxj="+boxj);  

        // set extra box to the color that we clicked on

            if (mode == 2) 
            {

                boxes[boxCount++] = new Box(e.getX(), e.getY(), randomColor());
            }    


              if ( mode == 1)

            {

               triangles[triangleCount++] = new Triangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 

                   randomColor());

            }



            repaint();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 

        {

         if      ( e.getSource()==TriangleButton ) { mode  = 1;}

     else if ( e.getSource()==boxButton ) { mode = 2;}

     else if ( e.getSource()==ovalButton) { mode = 3;}


    else if (e.getSource() == clearButton)

    {
        // release all existing boxes

        while (boxCount-- > 0) boxes[boxCount] = null;

            while (triangleCount-- > 0) triangles[triangleCount] = null;

            while (ovalCount-- > 0) ovals[ovalCount] = null;

    }

  repaint();   

        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 

        {

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)

        {   

         x1 = e.getX();

     y1 = e.getY();

     downX = e.getX();

     downY = e.getY();

     if ( mode == 3)

      {
          v = new Oval(e.getX(),e.getY(), randomColor());

          ovals [ovalCount]= v;

          ovalCount++; 

      }

   repaint();

        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
        {

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
        {

        }
public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e ) {}
```

public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e )

{

```
  upX = e.getX();

  upY = e.getY();

  if ( mode ==3)

  {

      int width;

      int height;

      width = upX - downX;

      height = upY - downY;

      v.w = width; 

      v.h = height; 

  }

  repaint();
```

}

```
        public void paint(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paint(g);   

            for (int i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) 

            {
                boxes[i].drawMe(g);

            }

  for ( int a=0; a<triangleCount; a++)

   {

      triangles[a].drawMe(g);

   }   

  for ( int b=0; b<ovalCount; b++)

  {

      ovals[b].drawMe(g);

  }

 }
```

}

This Is the other class for the box (connected to the main program to draw my box)

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Box 
{
    protected Color color;

    protected int x, y; // pixels from upper left to upper left corner

    // make a box

    public Box(int x1, int y1, Color c1) 
    {
        x = x1;

        y = y1;

        color = c1;
    }

    public void drawMe(Graphics g) 

    {
        g.setColor(color);

        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    }

    public void setColor(Color c) 

    {
        color = c;
    }

    public Color getColor() 

    {
        return color;
    }
}

Here is another class

package kaleidescope;

public class Point

{ 

int x;

int y;

public Point( int x1, int y1 )

{

   x = x1; y = y1;
}

}
```

Also this class

```
package kaleidescope;

import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Shape

{

protected Color color;

abstract public void drawMe( Graphics g ); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a "Clear" button and in the handler, set `boxCount` back to zero and call `repaint()`. You'll have to adjust `actionPerformed` to detect when the clear button was the source.

EDIT: Here's your code modified to add a clear function (just for boxes, but see below):

```
JButton boxButton;
JButton clearButton; // NEW

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("hi there.");
    new Kaleidescope();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    boxes = new Box[20];
    boxCount = 0;
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    boxButton = new JButton("Boxes");
    add(boxButton);
    boxButton.addActionListener(this);

    // NEXT 3 LINES ARE NEW
    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    add(clearButton);
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);

    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if (e.getSource() == boxButton) 
    {
        mode = 2;
        repaint();
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == clearButton)
    {
        // release all existing boxes
        while (boxCount-- > 0) boxes[boxCount] = null;

        // TODO: zero out all other display list items as well

        // redraw everything (which is now nothing)
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Since you don't show how you are maintaining the list of other shapes, I can't provide specific code for the TODO part. However, it would look quite similar to what I've posted.

EDIT 2:

Here's how I would recommend switching things around to use `ArrayList`s instead of arrays. I'll just describe how to change things for boxes; the other shapes would be similar.

1. Import `java.util.ArrayList`.
2. Eliminate the variable `boxCount`.
3. Change

   ```
   Box[] boxes;
   ```

   to

   ```
   ArrayList<Box> boxes;
   ```
4. Replace the lines

   ```
   boxes = new Box[20];
   boxCount = 0;
   ```

   with:

   ```
   boxes = new ArrayList<Box>(); // or new ArrayList<>() for Java 7+ compiler
   ```
5. Replace the line:

   ```
   boxes[boxCount++] = new Box(e.getX(), e.getY(), randomColor());
   ```

   with:

   ```
   boxes.add(new Box(e.getX(), e.getY(), randomColor()));
   ```
6. Replace the line:

   ```
   while (boxCount-- > 0) boxes[boxCount] = null;
   ```

   with:

   ```
   boxes.clear();
   ```
7. Replace the drawing loop:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) 
   {
       boxes[i].drawMe(g);
   }
   ```

   with:

   ```
   for (Box box : boxes) {
       box.drawMe(g);
   }
   ```

That's it. From the code that you've posted so far, I don't see a reason for having separate lists for boxes, triangles, and ovals. I would recommend that you just have a single display list of `Shape` objects that contains all of the shapes to be drawn (boxes, triangles, and ovals all mixed in together). Perhaps, though, in some other part of your code you are processing each list of objects separately; that might change my recommendation.

Comment: um do you mind writing it in a code, not sure if I understood? Also I want to clear everything not just the box?

Comment: if      ( e.getSource()==TriangleButton ) { mode  = 1;}
    else if ( e.getSource()==boxButton ) { mode = 2;}
    else if ( e.getSource()==ovalButton) { mode = 3;}
    
     else if (e.getSource() == clearButton)
     {
         // release all existing boxes
         while (boxCount-- > 0) boxes[boxCount] = null;
            while (triangleCount-- > 0) triangles[triangleCount] = null;
            while (ovalCount-- > 0) ovals[ovalCount] = null;
     }
   repaint();

Comment: When I did that they work but they also crash? is what I did wrong? Right I did not add the other shapes because it might get too long, but they are similar so is that right? what i did

Comment: @user3307524 - It looks right to me. If it crashed, what was the exception? Perhaps one of the arrays was `null`?

Comment: Ok So I added the ovals, and the exception says that there is something wrong with this line: ovals [ovalCount]= v;

Comment: @user3307524 - So what was the exception? What's v? Is the `ovals` array null?

Comment: Yes v is the Oval, no i set it to null. Here i will add it to my example.

Comment: I mean to say no they are not null when i declare it.

Comment: @user3307524 - Ah. Then this happens when you are adding an oval? The possibility there is that you are adding more ovals than will fit in your array, `ovalCount` is too large, and you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. The best solution there is either to carefully limit how many of each object type your code allows to be created or else switch from using arrays to using an `ArrayList` for each object type. `ArrayList` will dynamically grow in capacity to accommodate as many objects as you try to add to it.

Comment: um do you mind showing me an example not sure how to switch it?

Comment: @user3307524 - Done. As you will see, using an `ArrayList` is usually a lot simpler than managing your own array.

Comment: So my oval I used to drag it and make it bigger and smaller and now it crashes when i changed it to ArrayList? Does it have to do anything with that or it is another problem?

Comment: I think after i changed this those lines:  v = new Oval(e.getX(),e.getY(), randomColor());
        ovals [ovalCount]= v;
           ovalCount++;

Comment: to ovals.add(new Oval(e.getX(), e.getY(), randomColor()));

Comment: @user3307524 - Please start another question about that.